# Requirejs randomly makes calls to my server for dependency

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In the documentation (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html):

```
// contents of main.js:
require.config({
    paths: {
        foo: 'libs/foo-1.1.3'
    }
});

// contents of other.js:

// This code might be called before the require.config() in main.js
// has executed. When that happens, require.js will attempt to
// load 'scripts/foo.js' instead of 'scripts/libs/foo-1.1.3.js'
require( ['foo'], function( foo ) {

});
```

In my case, the path is set right before the 'require' statement, in the same function, in the same file:

```
loadBaseTemplates: function () {
            var self = this;

            //add path for future reference
            require.config({
                paths: {
                    'templates-base': globalProperties.urlPrefix + '/org/dust-ui/dist/js/templates/base/dustc' + self.platformType + '-min-' + globalProperties.swapFileVersion
                }
            });

            //load base templates
            require(['templates-base'], function () {
            });
        }
```

In very, very rare occurrences (less than 1% of total traffic), I get the following error in my server logs, which means the browser was making a GET request for templates-base.js

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:22:47:52 +0000] "GET /org/actions/templates-base.js HTTP/1.0" 500 575 1 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/
29.0"
```

This does not seem to be isolated to any particular browser.

Another thing to note is that I'm using the Optimizer.

Any help or insight will be much appreciated!

UPDATE:

Adding ALL occurrences of 'templates-base' in my application. All the code pasted here are all in the same file.

```
  if (contentJSON.arguments.needsCountryTemplates && contentJSON.arguments.needsClientTemplates) {
        require(['templates-base', 'templates-country', 'templates-client'], function () {

        });
    } else if (contentJSON.arguments.needsCountryTemplates) {
        require(['templates-base', 'templates-country'], function () {

        });
    } else if (contentJSON.arguments.needsClientTemplates) {
        require(['templates-base', 'templates-client'], function () {

        });
    } else {
        require(['templates-base'], function () {

        });
    }
```

And the very first require block:

```
require(['utility', 'jquery', 'dust'], function(utility) {
   $(function() {
       utility.setPlatformType();
       utility.loadBaseTemplates();
   });
});
```

Comment: The path in your log does not look at all like the path in your code. So it looks like the `require.config` call is not in effect when that module is loaded. Is `templates-base` present in a list of requirements to `define` or `require` anywhere *else* in your application?

Comment: Is it possible that the code in the snippet you've just added (the one with all the `if`s and `require(['templates-base', ...`) executes sometimes *before* the code in which you have the `require.config`? (Remember that RequireJS operates asynchronously which trips quite a few people.)

Comment: utility.loadBaseTemplates(); is called immediately after bootstraping, so i don't think that will happen. also, this also happens only less than 1% of the time.